# react native - eval of function

Tags: react-native, eval

I am able to call a function within react native using `this.function1()` and it runs without any issue.

However if I try to run the function like so:
`eval("this.function1()")` it returns the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.function1')`

Any ideas how I can use eval or similar in react native, to call a function ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why keep this.function1() in quotes?

Comment: Hi @SrishruthikAlle. I dont think the quotes make any difference. Have you any other ideas what might fix the issue ? Are there limitations with eval in react native ?